How to properly convert Python docker API's CancellableStream into readable string?
What I got:
Python code that executes commands inside docker container using docker API and then reads output from them:
def foo(some_command_list, workdir):
    output_list = []
    output_byte_str = b''
    for command in some_command_list:
            cmd_output = container.exec_run(command, stream=True, workdir=workdir, tty=True)
            for chunk in cmd_output.output:
               output_byte_str += chunk
            output_list.append(output_byte_str.decode('utf-8'))
    return output_list

the stdout (bool) and stderr (bool) are set by default to true.
The following function returns a list of strings.
My goal:

I believe this code is not done accordingly to best practices and standards of working with docker API. What should I change to make the code more readable and optimal?
Also i see that some command outputs appear multiple times in my output_list even though they were placed only once in the some_command_list, what am I missing?

I would be grateful for any pointers.

My first step would be to remove the call to container.exec_run() entirely.  (Without Docker, how and why might you "go inside" your running Python program and run more commands?)  A best case would be to remove any dependencies on the Docker API, for both permission and portability reasons.  What are these commands actually trying to do?

@DavidMaze How should I put commands into running docker container if I remove container.exec_run()? I am running these commands to configure already running docker container accordingly to user specified configuration (in other part of the script) and run code compilation that has to happen inside said container.

That sounds like you're missing a step in your image's entrypoint wrapper script or something else.  You shouldn't need to "put commands into running Docker container" in normal use.  Again, what actually are these commands?
